# Using Netgear Broadband 341U

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, netgear

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 platform and I have been trying to use Sprint Netgear 341 USB Modem. I have downloaded the Linux documentation from Netgear website and followed the instructions. I successfully installed the drivers and the device seems to be recognized by Ubuntu as it appears on NW and WiFi listing as "new broadband connection" however after following the steps for installation of the broadband connection using the "edit connections" feature nothing is happening i.e. the Netgear device doesn't work.

Unfortunately the Netgear documentation doesn't cover Ubuntu 14.04 but earlier versions of this OS. I don't know if this is a factor.

Any help on this would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb` (with the USB modem plugged in)?

Comment: I think is the following: Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1199:9055 Sierra Wireless, Inc. Gobi 9x15 Multimode 3G/4G LTE Modem (NAT mode). Is this what you meant?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.